# How to deal with product comparison website regarding Duplicate penalty and canonical tags?

Tags: asp.net-core, url, seo, sitemap

I have a product comparison site made by using asp.net core.

[image]

In there sample URL structure is this

```
https://test.com/specs/19-20/test1-vs-test2
```

I am adding canonical tags to above URL if the URL changed like below. At the head section of the 20-19 page I added a canonical tag that target to 19-20 page.

```
https://test.com/specs/20-19/test2-vs-test1
```

Now I want to add another product for comparison and that makes 3 products in comparison at same interface

So the URL will be like below

```
https://test.com/specs/19-20-21/test1-vs-test2-vs-test3
```

So in this case how I add canonical tags. Note that in my sitemap I am generating every possible URL to submit for indexing. Even 150 products make 11K URLS. so when It comes to 3 it will be hugely increased too.
Is this cause any duplicate penalty? Cause already there is a page to see test1 vs test2
Now Same page will be extend to display test1 vs test2 vs test3

I am confused with adding relevant tags to this post.

Comment: Are  https://test.com/specs/19-20/test1-vs-test2 and https://test.com/specs/20-19/test2-vs-test1 sharing the same page?

Comment: @RuikaiFeng yes., At the head section of the 20-19 page I added a canonical tag that target to 19-20 page. Updated the post with an screenshot. I have a product table where it has all the details of that product. So at comparison page I am compare them inside a table